# Ansible win_package stuck forever

Tags: ansible, nessus

I am using win_package module for installing "Nessus" in Windows 2016 server. But whenever I execute it, it hangs forever without response. Even after waiting for an hour, there is no response.

I have already kept Nessus installer in Windows server directory as mentioned in the code.

Please help.

Playbook main file:

```
---
- name: Windows Install Nessus
  gather_facts: yes
  hosts: windows
  vars_files:
  - /etc/ansible/vars/Win_Vars.yml
  tasks:
  - import_tasks: Install_Nessus.yml
```

Playbook Task file (Install_Nessus.yml):

```
- name: Install Nessus in Windows server
      win_package:
        path: C:\temp\Nessus-8.0.1-x64.msi
        state: present
```

Output:

> [root@localhost ansible]# ansible-playbook Win_Nessus_Install.yml
>   [DEPRECATION WARNING]: DEFAULT_ASK_SUDO_PASS option, In favor of
>   Ansible Become, which is a generic framework. See become_ask_pass. ,
>   use become instead. This feature will be removed in version 2.8.
>   Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting
>   deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg. [DEPRECATION WARNING]: The
>   sudo command line option has been deprecated in favor of the "become"
>   command line arguments. This feature will be removed in version 2.9.
>   Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting
>   deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg. SSH password: SUDO
>   password[defaults to SSH password]:
>
> PLAY [Windows OS Basic Settings2]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [target_windows]
>
> TASK [Install Nessus in Windows server]
>
> ---

Comment: Disclaimer: I was trying to install an EXE, not an MSI. In any case, what worked for me was to use the `'/SP-'` unattended installation flag as an argument to `win_package`. [This](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/InnoSetup_Switches_ExitCodes.html) is where I found this piece of information.

Comment: Sadle the `'/SP-'` trick is not working for me.